# Passing multiple id’s as parameter in api using nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am using nestjs and i new to this and i have a task to create an api
http://localhost:8000/companies/4/5/8….

How can i create this api with GET(‘:id’) method which takes multiple paramters.

Comment: Api should take multiple id’s in url.

Answer (score -1):

Your api could be designed this way:
`http://localhost:8000/compaines?id=1,2,3`

So your nodejs code would need to be able to look at the query parameter and then use that to fetch the right set of `companies`.

Note: Think of how you would indicate errors if there are any. Example one of the ids passed is not present. Do you want to fail the whole call with a 404 or do you want to send whatever you have.